# How to read html tags using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read html tag using beautifulsoap and checking whether some tags are available or missing.

I am reading the file using beautifulsoup and then using it in my test files.

Here what i tried but didn't get it to work:

```
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUp(name):

            name.html = None
            with open("index.html") as frd:
                name.html = frd.read()
                name.soup = BeautifulSoup(name.html)
            if not name.html:
                raise Exception('cant read')    

        def testing(self)
         assert self.soup.find('html') == 'html'
          #Raise : error
```

I can't find html tag using find() function in soup (tried printing it to see the output but dint work). How can I raise an exception if HTML tag is missing in a html file?

Comment: what's the exact error you getting? I see you don't have : after the definition!

Comment: assert self.soup.find('html') == 'html'
AssertionError

Comment: Okay, can you try another answer I just posted?

Comment: Show more code. Specifically, where you initialize `soup`.

Comment: Okay, so try the answer, it's working fine!

Comment: i m sorry abt that!!! Yes its working thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as when you are using find it returns the beautified strings or None! So, this thing I can suggest!

```
try:
    assert self.soup.find('html') != None
except AssertionError, e:
    raise Exception("HTML Tag is missing!")
```

Comment: Sorry , does not work !! I have Html tag in my file but it still raises an exception that html is missing

Comment: when it finds something assert with None:)

Comment: How can I use assertEqual here , I tried self.assertEqual(self.soup.find('html'),"html") , is it correct?

Comment: you can't do that as you are comparing not None and "html" and that's totally wrong!